# Cancelling a long "string" of Task continuations properly? Forcing Task execution order and thread usage?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a class that strings together small chunks of IO work as `Task` continuations. Each time a piece of work is received a new `Task` is created, it is then added as a continuation to the `LastCreatedTask`. I am trying to determine the proper way to cancel all of these `Task` properly?

Here is my setup currently

```
private Task LastCreatedTask { get; set; }
private CancellationTokenSource TaskQueueTokenSource { get; set; }

public void ScheduleChunk(IOWorkChunk inChunk, int procTimeout)
{
    Task ioChunkProcessTask = CreateProcessTask(inChunk, procTimeout);

    LastCreatedTask.ContinueWith(
        (t) => ioChunkProcessTask.Start(), 
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);

    LastCreatedTask = ioChunkProcessTask;
}

private Task CreateProcessTask(IOWorkChunk inChunk, int procTimeout)
{
    // Create a TokenSource that will cancel after a given timeout period
    var ProcessTimeoutTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(procTimeout));

    // Create a TokenSource for the Task that is a 
    // link between the timeout and "main" token source
    var ProcessTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(
        TaskQueueTokenSource.Token, 
        ProcessTimeoutTokenSource.Token);

    // Create a Task that will do the actual processing
    Task ioChunkProcessTask = new Task(() =>
    {
        if(!ProcessTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            inChunk.DoProcessing(ProcessTokenSource.Token);
    }, ProcessTokenSource.Token);

    return ioChunkProcessTask;
}
```

So in the function `ScheduleChunk` a "chunk" of IO work (and a timeout) are passed to `CreateProcessTask` which creates a `Task` that will do the actual processing of the IO work. A `CancellationToken` is passed to this `Task` which is made by chaining two `CancellationTokenSources` together.

The first is the "main" `CancellationTokenSource`; I want to be able to simply call `Cancel` on this source to cancel all of the `Task` that are chained. The second source is one that will automagically cancel after some given period of time (this stops long running/stalled IO chunks).

Finally once the constructed `Task` is returned to `ScheduleChunk` is it added as a continuation to the `LastCreatedTask` which is the last task the was added as a continuation. This in effect makes a chain of `Task` that run in order one after the other.

**1.** *Is my method above the proper way to cancel the chain of `Task`? By calling `Cancel` on the `TaskQueueTokenSource`?*

**2.** *Is the use of the `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously` along with continuations the proper way to ensure that these `Task` are executed in order one after the other?*

**3.** *Is there a way to specify that I would like the same thread from the underlying TPL `ThreadPool` to work on this chain of `Task`?*

From what I can tell a new thread should not be created for each continuation point, though it is possible at some point that a new thread could pickup the chain.

Comment: Even though you've called `Cancel` on the cancellation token, you still will need to check if the token has been cancelled in all of the tasks..

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to add that in there. I will make an edit shortly.

Comment: Can you use await? Normally, all chains of tasks should be expressed as an async method. This makes all of this easy.

Comment: Admitting my lack of knowledge, I am not sure how using async/await here would make this easier? I understand async/await to a point, just not how it would be applied. So to answer, no I don't know if I can or how I would?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing code does not work at all:

```
LastCreatedTask.ContinueWith((t) => ioChunkProcessTask)
```

This continuation merely returns a task whose result will be set to a constant object almost immediately. That's all it does.

Really, this code is structured awkwardly. This is much better:

```
async Task RunProcessing() {
 while (...) {
  await CreateProcessTask(...);
 }
}
```

`await` is made for sequencing async actions. `await` can replace `ContinueWith` most of the time.

The cancellation looks good. Maybe it can be simplified a bit but it's working fine.

Regarding 3, you should never need this. Thread affinity is a rare thing and to be avoided. There is no way to do this exactly as asked. Please elaborate what you want to achieve.

---

If you insist on using Task.Run, here's a sketch:

```
Task CreateProcessTask(IOWorkChunk inChunk, int procTimeout)
{
    // Create a TokenSource that will cancel after a given timeout period
    var ProcessTimeoutTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(procTimeout));

    // Create a TokenSource for the Task that is a 
    // link between the timeout and "main" token source
    var ProcessTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(
        TaskQueueTokenSource.Token, 
        ProcessTimeoutTokenSource.Token);

    return Task.Run(() => {
        inChunk.DoProcessing(ProcessTokenSource.Token);
    }, ProcessTokenSource.Token);
}
```

Comment: Oops another thing I forgot, I forgot `.Start` in the `ContinueWith` method. I will edit the code above.

Comment: Yeah, the task ctor and Start() are anti-patterns. I was about to write that. There is no need for that. Use Task.Run. Here, I do not see why you are using the thread-pool at all and why use continuations at all? You do not have async IO since DoProcessing is synchronous. You could run all of this in a single synchronous method I believe.

Comment: Could you edit the first code sample to show using `Task.Run`? I guess I am confused now. // I do have async IO, behind each `IOWorkChunk` is a `SerialPort`/USB driver communication that happens. Most of these communications need to happen in order thus why I went with continuations. Each chunk would be executed in order and one at a time. // And yes as for 3 I don't think I need to venture there the more I think about it.

Comment: But DoProcessing is not async. No async IO here.

Comment: Added Task.Run code. Now, there is no need to the dreaded Task.ctor and Task.Start anymore.

Comment: Please bear with me, wouldn't creating the `Task` with `Run` "start" the execution of the task "instantly"? When the method you have in your answer above returns wouldn't the `Task` already be running? This breaks my need for each chunk to run in order...?

Comment: Yes, it's best practice to only have hot tasks that are running. The await loop serializes all those tasks. Do you see why?

Comment: I think I am on the edge of understanding it... I guess I am confused by the `while` loop in you example `RunProcessing` method...? This would be an infinite loop correct? But it would effectively be "ran" only when the function is called?.... // Could you fill in the function more so I can make sure.

Comment: The code is basically complete. I assume there is some "event" that makes you want to start the sequence. At that time you call RunProcessing. I assume there is some event that makes you want to stop. Put that condition instead of the `true`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103228/discussion-between-kdecker-and-usr).

Answer (score 0):

Use a shared cancellation token that you pass to each task instead of creating a unique one for each task.  When you cancel that token, all tasks using that token will then know to stop processing.

You edited after I answer, so I'll reply to your individual numbered questions:

**1.** *Is my method above the proper way to cancel the chain of Task? By calling Cancel on the TaskQueueTokenSource?*

[According to msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607(v=vs.110).aspx), best practices is to create one token, then passing that same token to each task.

**2.** *Is the use of the TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously along with continuations the proper way to ensure that these Task are executed in order one after the other?*

No, you Tasks are meant to be run in parallel, the best practices are instead to have the tasks that rely on ordering to be call each other down a chain, The first calling the second and so on.  Alternatively you wait until the first task is complete before you start the second task.

**3.** *Is there a way to specify that I would like the same thread from the underlying TPL ThreadPool to work on this chain of Task?*

It is very unlikely that you you should be doing this, part of the purpose of the thread pool and the Task Asynchronous Programming (TAP) and TPL is to abstract the explicit threading away.  You aren't guaranteed the thread that a task is ran on or even whether or not a new thread is generated for that task without a lot of work.

That said, if, for some reason you really do need to do this [a custom task scheduler is the answer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I think this is what I am doing with `TaskQueueTokenSource`. This is combined with `ProcessTimeoutTokenSource` in `CreateProcessTask` to create a `CancellationTokenSource.Token` that is passed to the `Task`?

Comment: I am in the midst of replying to the questions you asked while I was submitting my answer, but according to MSDN you only pass one token to all the tasks.

Comment: I added answers to your three explicit questions.

Comment: The MSDN article linked for 1 does not explicitly state that passing the same token to each task is the best practice, that is just what they do in the example. Also, I am "basically" doing this am I not?

Comment: As for the answer to 2, this is what I am currently doing. I am "chainging" my `Task`s with `ContinueWith`. From what I can tell this has the effect of "calling each other down a chain"?